# Alternate tool for a GhostDoc type of tool

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2005

Is there a tool for .NET which will generate explanations (comments) of code if we give it function or event handlers (like [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) which we feel is not a good tool)?

Comment: Are you serious? How can a computer explain code? The tool you are looking for is the author of the code!

Comment: Hey, stop referring to programmers as tools!

Comment: not for generating complete things ,,for generating the prototype

Comment: Atomineerutils seems goodhttp://www.atomineerutils.com/compare.php

Comment: I've been using GhostDoc for a long time now, but I'm starting to get sick of the buggy updates they've been releasing lately. Did you ever find an alternative (free) tool?

Comment: Chastening to think how @DavidHeffernan's comment has aged over the last decade!  Now there are VS ChatGPT plugins that can do a pretty good job of summarizing code.  This question should probably include something about them these days.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you start a comment with /// in VS2010, it'll create basic parameters in XML for you based on the function you're commenting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722812.aspx

So typing /// before the function `startMonitor(ManagementScope scope)` gives...

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="scope"></param>
static void startMonitor(ManagementScope scope)
```

If you're wanting to generate decent documentation from these, I suggest https://github.com/EWSoftware/SHFB as your first stop. It's pretty ace.

Comment: VS 2005 will create XML comments on a triple forward-slash as well.

Comment: Yet another reason VS is a great product. This works in the standalone Visual Express products as well, like VWD2008/10, VC# 2008/10.

Comment: All XML commenting is going to be similar to Ghostdoc - it's the quality of the comments that you enter which matter, not the program used to generate them. The comments generated automatically are only going to be placeholders for the signature of the method - you'll still need to fill them in with useful information, otherwise your documentation generated will be pretty slim.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, `///` doesn't generate any documentation, just empty XML tags. Where GhostDoc shines is in generating MSDN style documentation (including the verbiage) automatically, based on contextual information such as property, class, visibility, usages etc.

Here are some true alternatives:

- [Atomineer](http://www.atomineerutils.com/) (bit cheaper than GhostDoc)
- Resharper (works only if you enable XML Comments for the project, but is nowhere near as good as above two. can also copy XML comments from base classes/interfaces).

Now, whatever you do, please do not produce *[undocumentation](http://blog.codinghorror.com/avoiding-undocumentation/)*! :)

Comment: Finally, I have a name for the horror that MSDN documentation is: "Undocumentation".

Comment: You say not to produce _undocumentation_, and yet that is precisely what GhostDoc does.

Comment: You’re supposed to write something afterwards. Don’t just leave it at that. That’s what I meant by not producing undocumentation. :)

Comment: GhostDoc does not do anything you can't already do by typing `///<TAB>`.  It makes up comments from the names of things, but that's pointless.  Information that can be gleaned from the names of things is a waste of documentation.  Documentation should explain important information too long to put in the name.  GhostDoc can't do that.  Now if you think GhostDoc does something that `///<TAB>` can't do, I'd be interested to know what that is.  But [this article from a year ago](https://dzone.com/articles/ghost-doc-says-the-damndest-things) shows that GhostDoc still produces undocumentation.

Comment: @Mrchief I'm not sure why you insist on making it personal.  Are you the author of GhostDoc?  Is that why you take such offense at criticisms of it?

Comment: No Ryan, I'm not. I don't see how I'm making it personal. I was trying to clarify if anything.

Comment: "I cannot show you what you refuse to see" is making it personal.  I'm not refusing to see anything.  I just happen to disagree with you, and I gave clear reasons why.  If you want to debate those reasons, go ahead (though then we should take it to a chat room).  If you want to decide that someone who doesn't recognize the genius of GhostDoc is just obstinately refusing to grasp the obvious, well...that's rude and not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/). It will work with Visual Studio 2005 projects. There are also downloads still available for [nDoc](http://ndoc.sourceforge.net/). It had its heyday around 2005, but I think little or no development has taken place since.

If you're looking for something that will actually prepopulate code comments for you, I'm not sure you can do much better than GhostDoc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no even one serious **GhostDoc Alternative**

- **Doxygen** from [doxygen.nl](http://doxygen.nl) for Visual Studio 2005 & 2008
- **LuaDoc** from [github.io/luadoc](http://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc) a documentation generator tool for Lua source code
- **Atomineer** from [atomineerutils.com](http://atomineerutils.com) just 30 days free
- **Sandcastle** from [github.io/SHFB](http://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/) Help File Builder Documentation
- **Swagger UI** from is [swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/](http://swagger.io/tools/swagger-ui/) REST API Documentation Tool
- **Daux.io** from [github.com/dauxio/daux.io](http://github.com/dauxio/daux.io)  is a documentation generator for PHP

I hope that starts a new opensource one by myself very soon.
PS: please update me if you find a struggle or mistake or any new one.